# continuous images of open intervals

Tags: gn.general-topology

The well-known Hahn-Mazurkiewicz theorem characterizes those nonempty Hausdorff spaces $X$ that admit a continuous surjection $\alpha: [0, 1] \to X$ from the closed unit interval: it is necessary and sufficient that $X$ be a compact, connected, locally connected metrizable space.

My Googling skills did not enable me to locate a nice way of characterizing Hausdorff spaces $X$ that admit a continuous surjection $(0, 1) \to X$ from an *open* interval. Is there one?

Comment: Two thoughts:  (1)  every space that is the image of $[0,1]$ is the image of $(0,1)$; (2)  we can replace $(0,1)$ with $\mathbb{R}$.  I wonder it could be as simple as asking that  $X$ be a path-connected countable union of spaces satisfying Hahn-Mazurkowicz.

Comment: One such $X$ is the [Warsaw circle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Warsaw_circle#Warsaw_Circle), which may indicate the difficulty of getting a similarly nice characterization.

Comment: @JeffStrom I wondered the same thing.

Comment: @JeffStrom: Any path-connected countable union of Hahn-Mazurkowicz spaces can certainly be covered by a map from $(0,1)$.  Simply cover each one of the Hahn-Mazurkowicz subspaces one by one, interspersed with paths between their endpoints.

Comment: @EricWofsey:  I was busy typing this up below.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Call $A$ an HM-space if there is a continuous surjection $I\to A$ (where $I$ is the closed interval $[0,1]$).  Note that if $A$ is an HM-space, then it is path-connected.

Theorem: If $X$ is path-connected, then the following are equivalent:

1. $X = \bigcup_{n=1}^\infty A_n$ where each $A_n$ is an HM-space
2. there is a continuous surjection $\mathbb{R} \to X$
3. there is a continuous surjection $(0,\infty) \to X$
4. there is a continuous surjection  $[0,\infty) \to X$.

Proof:
Clearly (2) and (3) are equivalent;  let's prove (3) implies (1). 
If $f:(0,\infty) \to X$ is a continuous surjection, let $A_n = f([n-1,n])$.  Then 
$A_n$ is evidently an HM-space and $X$ is the indicated countable union.

Now we show (1) implies (4).  if $X = \bigcup_{n=1}^\infty A_n$ with each $A_n$ an HM-space, then we can choose surjective paths $\alpha_n: [2(n-1),2n-1]\to A_n$; write $x_n = \alpha_n(0)$ and $y_n= \alpha_n(1)$.  Since $X$ is path-connected, we can find paths $\beta_n:[2n-1,2n]\to X$ from $y_n$ to $x_{n+1}$.  Concatenating these paths gives the desired surjection $0,\infty) \to X$.

Finally, since  there is a continuous surjection $\mathbb{R}\to [0,\infty )$, (4) implies (2).$\quad \square$

Just musing:  there is a partial order on spaces defined by $X< Y$ if there is a continuous surjection $Y \to X$.  Hahn-Mazurkowicz classifies $\{ X \mid X < I\}$.  The equivalence of (2), (3) and (4) shows that half-open intervals are "equivalent" to open ones (i.e., both $(0,1)< [0,1)$ and $[0,1) < (0,1)$);  and closed ones are different, being compact.  Finally, note that a Peano space (i.e., HM-space) $X$ is "equivalent" in this sense to $I$ if and only if it is the domain of a nonconstant continuous function $f:X\to \mathbb{R}$.

Comment: Well, that was easy. Thanks! That might be the best one could hope for, but I'll wait a while to see if there are other responses before accepting.

Comment: Incidentally, I think the usual term for HM-space is Peano space.

Comment: Just to clarify, $I$ here denotes the *closed* unit interval?

Comment: @NateEldredge That's right.

Comment: Jeff's musings prompted me to think that maybe a good name for spaces which admit a continuous surjection from $(0, \infty)$ is "LP-space", for (inductive) Limit of Peano spaces, by way of analogy with LF-spaces in analysis (limits of Frechet spaces). If I'm not mistaken, based on Jeff's description, the category of spaces that admit continuous surjections from $\mathbb{R}$ has colimits of countable chains; it follows that the same category has filtered colimits. I then wonder: are compact LP-spaces the same as Peano spaces, and are they the finitely presentable objects in the category LP?

Comment: Well, I could be talking to myself here, but even if $\hom(P, -): LP \to Set$ preserves filtered colimits for Peano spaces $P$, I don't think it's correct that every LP-space is a filtered colimit of Peano spaces, as locally connected spaces are closed under colimits in $Top$ but the Warsaw circle isn't locally connected. In other words, LP-space isn't such a great name after all. It's easy to get tripped up here!

Comment: This characterization appears in http://arxiv.org/pdf/1404.5876.pdf (see Proposition 3.2). The author calls these spaces *$\sigma$-Peano spaces*.