# Which topological spaces admit embeddings into Euclidean spaces

Tags: gn.general-topology, duality, embeddings

I'm interested in the dual question to:
[continuous images of open intervals](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/168084/continuous-images-of-open-intervals), about surjections onto open intervals.

Namely, if $X$ is a topological space, when can we guarantee that there exists a topological embedding of $X$ into some Euclidean space?

Comment: There is ambiguity between the title question and body question. (“Embedding” [*usually*](//en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Embedding#General_topology) means that $f$ is a homeomorphism $X\to f(X)$ with subspace topology on the latter.)

Comment: Another thing which should be clarified is whether $d$ represents finite number or whether products of infinitely many copies are allowed, too.

Comment: @MartinSleziak should be finite.

Comment: It's fine I'll accept the answer but would be open to other posts (purely for scientific interest)

Comment: @FrancoisZiegler, the only change in my edit was to delete one of the two 'which's in the title "Which topological spaces which admit continuous injections into Euclidean spaces".  That seemed like a clear typo, but, if it changed meaning, I have no problem with its being rolled back.  (@‍New_Topologist_On_The_Block had made an edit before me, which may be what you saw.)

Comment: I know, but the result is so nice that I have to accept it :0

Comment: @New_Topologist_On_The_Block Then I suggest changing the question & title question back to “embedding” so that it matches the answer you accepted.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There's an old theorem of Deák that gives an interesting characterization. 
Given a topological space $X$, define a relation on subsets of $X$ as follows: we write $U \sqsubseteq V$ if and only if $\overline{U} \subseteq V$.

**Theorem** (Deák): A separable metrizable space is homeomorphic to a subset of $\mathbb R^n$ if and only if its topology has a subbasis generated by $\leq n+1$ collections of open sets, each totally ordered by $\sqsubseteq$.

For example, to generate the topology of $\mathbb R^2$ with $3$ collections of this kind, think of how $3$ families of open half-planes can be used to form a small open triangle around every point of the plane.
This theorem appears in

> J. Deák, "A new characterization of the class of subspaces of a Euclidean space," *Studia Sci. Math. Hungar.* **11** (1980), pp. 253-258.

I don't have a link to this paper, but the result is discussed in section 2 of [this](https://wrbrian.files.wordpress.com/2012/01/neight2.pdf) paper, which contains a few other related things as well.
My favorite part of this theorem is that by changing it a little, one arrives at an interesting (to me) conjecture:

**Conjecture**: A separable metrizable space is homeomorphic to a subset of $\mathbb R^n$ if and only if its topology has a subbasis generated by $\leq n+1$ collections of open sets, each totally ordered by $\subseteq$.

The conjecture is true for $n=1$, but I don't think it's known for larger $n$. (Does the Klein bottle have a subbasis generated by $4$ nested collections of open sets? Even this special case does not seem trivial to me.)

Comment: Note that the question was originally about the existence of a continuous injection, which is a priori weaker (for non-separable metrizable spaces it's weaker, just considering an uncountable discrete space of at most continuum cardinal). (But the question might be amended retroactively...)