# Dense embeddings into Euclidean space

Tags: gn.general-topology, gt.geometric-topology, mg.metric-geometry, embeddings, metric-embeddings

The question is a follow-up on this [old post](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/357445/which-topological-spaces-admit-embeddings-into-euclidean-spaces).  Fix a positive integer $d$ and consider $\mathbb{R}^d$ with its usual Euclidean topology.  Given a metric space $(X,\delta_X)$, what conditions are needed for $(X,\delta_X)$ to admit a continuous (preferably bi-Lipschitz) embedding into a dense subset of $\mathbb{R}^d$?

Comment: As an example, a cylinder ($S^1\times\mathbb{R}$) has such an embedding. Let $\gamma:\mathbb{R\to R^+\times R}$ be a dense injective map. Then $(\theta,t)\to (\gamma_x(t)\cos\theta,\gamma_x(t)\sin\theta,\gamma_y(t))$ is such an embedding.